# Adobe DTM javascript embed without iframe

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I have a simple question. I'm looking to embed javascript code that creates some html and displays an image. I know there are options to embed this code as a third party tag as sequential html/JS or non sequential html/JS. Do both of these options create an iframe for that embed code? Is there a way to not be within an iframe?

Comment: The only one that creates an iframe is non-sequential html

Answer (score 0):

If the tag has been placed as **"Non-Sequential HTML"** then DTM outputs the code as an iframe.

**"Sequential HTML"** type will use document.write() to output the content synchronously.